# When I add image in my Latex file with TexMaker in windows, I got an error

Tags: latex, texmaker

when I add image in my Latex file with TexMaker in windows, I got an error. My code is following:

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{first1.png}
\caption{iamgeTitle}
\end{figure}
```

show error: undefined control sequence \includegraphics

after that when I try to add 
    \usepackage{graphicx}
show error: Can be used only in preamble.

I googled it for solve the problem but failed. How can I solved the problem.

Comment: The preamble is the part between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`. This is where you should place `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: Thanks @Werner. It's worked. From your answer, now I have learn some basic of LaTex. Thankz again